# jquery scroll function issue in webkit

Tags: jquery

This fires a jquery function when the page is 300px from the bottom, works fine in firefox but in webkit browsers like chrome, it fires after scrolling even 1 pixel.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var timeout = '';

    var $scollEl=$('body').scroll(function (e) { 
        var intBottomMargin = 500; 
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        //if less than intBottomMargin px from bottom 

        if ($scollEl.scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $scollEl.height() - intBottomMargin) {
          timeout = setTimeout(function(){ 
                $("#next-paginav")[0].click(); 
          }, 300);
        }
    });
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle of the code.
http://jsfiddle.net/LnmsR/2/

Try in chrome - fires immediately, then in firefox it fires at the bottom, like it should.
What exactly is the bug here and does anyone know how to make this work in webkit?

Comment: I'm running Chrome 25 and it's working correctly.

Comment: Working fine on Chrome 26 http://screencast.com/t/bFQgf61V

Comment: Uh... I'm so confused.
Are you guys using chrome on windows or OS X?

Comment: Here's chrome on OS X (same in safari).
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/26739594/Screen%20Capture2013-04-03%2002_34_22.mov

Answer (score 0):

I use this code

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).height()-$(window).height()-$(window).scrollTop() < 300) {
        // your code
    });
});
```